# Vector formatting C++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm new with vectors and I am trying to display a vector in a square like you can display a array in a square. Is that possible or do you have to display more than one vector as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int>v(3);
    vector<int>w(3);
    vector<int>x(3);
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        v[i] = i;
        w[i] = i;
        x[i] = i;
        cout << v[i] << " " << w[i] << " " << x[i] << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Display:

```
0 0 0 
1 1 1 
2 2 2
```

How do i display one vector in a square? Remember the display is important at this stage and not the values of the vector!!

Comment: Since you're counting 1 to 3, inclusive, you would be out of bounds when i == 3

Comment: Yes and it displayed in a square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're code is not correct. Vectors, like all arrays in C++, are 0-indexed; thus the valid indexes go from `0` to `size() - 1`. Your code uses index `size()`, and thus has undefined behaviour.

Unlike you insist, the values *are* rather important when you use them as indexes to your vectors. If you simply want to display numbers, you don't necessarily need any vectors at all (and you can choose your ranges at will):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i)
    std::cout << i << ' ' << i << ' ' << i << '\n';
```

And no, you don't need several vectors to display "a square of values". If you want to output the contents of a single vector to multiple lines, all you got to do is decide how many elements you want to have on a single line, and simply output a newline character after every this many elements, i.e.

```
std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8 };
int elements_on_this_line = 0,
    elements_to_output_per_line = 3;
for (int i: vec) {
    std::cout << i;
    elements_on_this_line++;
    if (elements_on_this_line == elements_to_output_per_line) {
        std::cout << '\n';
        elements_on_this_line = 0;
    } else {
        std::cout << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: I am starting at 1 and not at 0 on my for loop. `for(int i = 1; i <= 3;i++)` and that is the same as `for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)`

Comment: It is more convenient in the fact that i can start numbering from 1 and dont have to start at 0.

Comment: The values are not important at this stage.

Comment: @JohanDela, yes they are, because you use them to index your vectors. The vectors have a limited amount of valid indexes (as I explained in my answer), and you go beyond them.

Comment: @JohanDela You should learn to love counting from zero instead of fighting it, it's just how we roll.

Comment: i understand what you saying, but i am now trying to display one vector as a square

Comment: @JohanDela (and eq-) no, it's not. The former runs iterations with i = 1, i = 2, and i = 3. The latter only runs iterations with i = 0, and i = 1.

Comment: @FredOverflow i do know i am use to it. I know it will display from the value 0 to 2 in the grid if the loop is `for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)` like I say the values now is not to important, the display is.

Comment: @JohanDela, a for loop by itself will not display any values; the program will output the values you choose it to. Those aren't inherently tied to your loop conditions, but if you use your loop variable as an index, start from `0`.

Comment: @eq Like i have said the values at this stage is not important the display is. This is not in the program that i am writing.

Comment: @JohanDela, if you have already made up your mind, why bother asking anything? Values *used for indexing* are important at all stages!

Comment: I am not going to display 1 2 3 the whole time i am going to display diffident combinations of values.

Comment: @eq Can you please enplane to me firstly, can i display one vector in a grid with different values? eg. ` 1 2 3` on line one ` 4 5 6` on line 2...

Comment: @JohanDela, yes you can. Simply output a newline character after every N elements from the vector.

Comment: @MadKeithV I dont have access to the chat room. I am new.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to display a vector in a square like you can display a array in a square. Is that possible

Sure, why not?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8};
    auto it = vec.begin();
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x)
        {
            std::cout << *it++ << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed and the code to do the following:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  vector<vector<int> > v;
  int k = 0;
  for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    v.push_back ( vector<int>() );
    for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
    v[i].push_back ( k++ );
}
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) 
{
  for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
    cout<<v[i][j] <<' ';
    cout<<'\n';
}
}
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Since the values are the same you could just do:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int>v = {1,2,3};
    for(auto& i : v)
        std::cout << i << " " << i << " " << i << std::endl;
}
```